# Outlook Add-in REST call error

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to mark (flag) a message using the Outlook rest API, but I keep getting error messages. I've tried with different rest URLs but it doesn't help - the errors just varies.

Important values in the manifest for allowing this I believe are:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
...
<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
...
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
```

Here is the part I'm trying to do that causes error:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result)
{
    if (result.status === "succeeded")
    {
        var accessToken = result.value;
        var itemId = getItemRestId();
        var restUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + "/api/v2.0/messages/" + itemId;

        var request = {
            url: restUrl,
            type: "PATCH",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "Flag": { "FlagStatus": "Flagged" } },
            headers: { 
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, 
                "Conntent-Type": "application/json" 
            }
        };

        $.ajax(request)
            .done(function (item)
            {
                // dome something
            })
            .fail(function (error)
            {
                // handle error
            });
    }
    else
    {
        // handle error
    }
});

function getItemRestId()
{
    if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS')
    {
        return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
    }
    else
    {
        return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
            Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
            Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.Beta
        );
    }
}
```

This code above will result in the error:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

If I try to JSON.stringify() the data attribute of the request I get:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

If I change the rest URL to (seen in older samples):

```
'https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/'+ itemId;
```

And the headers attribute of the request to (seen in older samples):

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Then I get the following error instead:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorAccessDenied\",\"message\":\"The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth.\"}}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "error": {
      "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
      "message": "The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth."
    }
  },
  "status": 403,
  "statusText": "Forbidden"
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or missing here?

I'm debugging in Outlook 2016 and the account is Office 365.

**UPDATE: Fiddler outputs**

**Here is the request my own sample sends (results in 403 Forbidden)**
**Exact error:** *{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth."}}*

```
PATCH https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/AAMkAGNmMDllMTVhLTI3ZDctNDYxZS05ZWM5LTA3ZWQzMzYyNDBiOABGAAAAAAD6OQOAoKyKT6R02yYFe0bIBwD5fUzv7OgQQYAILztCFSSWAALg591rAAC382lxTQ2HQpUKZsAGTeWVAARPu37CAAA= HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Authorization: Bearer <long token code removed...>
Referer: https://localhost:44394/MessageRead.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$da-DK
Accept-Language: da-DK
Origin: https://localhost:44394
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: outlook.office.com
Content-Length: 33
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"Flag":{"FlagStatus":"Flagged"}}
```

**Here is the request the demo project sends (results in 200 OK)**

```
PATCH https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/AAMkAGNmMDllMTVhLTI3ZDctNDYxZS05ZWM5LTA3ZWQzMzYyNDBiOABGAAAAAAD6OQOAoKyKT6R02yYFe0bIBwD5fUzv7OgQQYAILztCFSSWAALg591rAAC382lxTQ2HQpUKZsAGTeWVAARPu37CAAA= HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Authorization: Bearer <long token code removed...>
Referer: https://<company.domain.com>:1443/outlookaddindemo/RestCaller/RestCaller.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$da-DK
Accept-Language: da-DK
Origin: https://<company.domain.com>:1443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: outlook.office.com
Content-Length: 47
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "Flag": {
    "FlagStatus": "Flagged"
  }
}
```

The only difference I can see is that the 2nd request payload seems formatted for reading while data wise being identical to the previous one.

I can't seem to find the problem here - I even made sure that both projects use the same version of JQuery.

Comment: What is the version of your Outlook client? There was a known bug in Outlook 2016 regarding tokens for REST.

Comment: It is in the original post, client is Outlook 2016 for Windows. But it could just as well be Outlook 2013 or Outlook.com/Office365 in a browser. This has to work in all of them.

Comment: If this is indeed an unfixed bug in Outlook 2016 for Windows, does anyone know of a workaround or are you just out of luck if you're working with Outlook 2016 for Windows?

Comment: The bug was fixed, that's why I'm asking for your version. Check File->Office Account, then look for the About Outlook section. It should list a version and build.

Comment: The version reads: 2016 MSO (16.0.8730.2175) 32-bit. I doubt it's the bug though since I have just tried a demo project that flags a message via the REST API and it works in my client... I have used Fiddler to check both requests and they appear to be identical, but mine just doesn't work for some reason :(

Comment: I have updated my post with Fiddler outputs of the request from both projects.

Comment: What is the value of the <Permissions> element in your add-in manifest?

Comment: It should be visible in the first code block of the post unless you refer to some other element? ReadWriteItem

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry. That's your problem. I'll post an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need write access to the item via REST, you need to specify `ReadWriteMailbox` in the `Permissions` element in your manifest. Despite it's name, `ReadWriteItem` doesn't give you a token with the proper scope. Any permission level other than `ReadWriteMailbox` gives an item-scoped token, and as the error says, the operation you're trying to do doesn't support item-scoped OAuth.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api for details, but here's the relevant bit:

> **Add-in permissions and token scope**
>
> It is important to consider what level of access your add-in will need via the REST APIs. In most cases, the token returned by `getCallbackTokenAsync` will provide read-only access to the current item only. This is true even if your add-in specifies the `ReadWriteItem` permission level in its manifest.
>
> If your add-in will require write access to the current item or other items in the user's mailbox, your add-in must specify the `ReadWriteMailbox` permission level in its manifest. In this case, the token returned will contain read/write access to the user's messages, events, and contacts.

Comment: That is so odd! I could have sworn that I had initially put that value in there, because I have read the article and know that it had to be set to Mailbox and not Item, so I didn't even look there anymore... Well I guess that's why it's always good to have someone else's eyes on things :) It works not thanks!

Comment: Aha! I see now what happened. I had copied the manifest file (with site specific URLs etc) to the web project of the solution, so that it would be part of the output when publish. However this is not the manifest that is used when launching the solution in VS. So I had made the change to the manifest file, just not the manifest file used when debugging in VS.